# ASP.NET active directory authentication User.IsInRole

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication, roleprovider

I developed an ASP.NET Intranet application. Now I was asked to add authentication for the application - it should be based on Active Directory. The user should not fill in any login or password.
 
From within ASP.NET C# code I should be able to check something like this:

```
if (User.IsInRole("MyApplicationReaders"))
{
     doSomething();
}
else if (User.IsInRole("MyApplicationAdmins"))
{
     doSomethingElse();
}
```

MyApplicationReaders and MyApplicationAdmins are names of Active Directory groups.
Can you please point me to some easy step-by-step tutorial how to achieve this? I failed to find any :-(

Answer (score 2):

Try to search harder.

You have to add to configuration file authentication method:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

And also add authorization rules:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="DomainName\Bob, DomainName\Mary" />
  <allow roles="BUILTIN\Administrators, DomainName\Manager" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

This this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx) for help.

PS: After you'll add windows authentication to your app you will be able to check `User.IsInRole` for authenticated users. But in some browsers your users will be promted to enter their's windows credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can set IIS to authenticate users automatically, but typically you implement your own authorization scheme.  In the past, I have used a database to map my AD accounts to application roles/permissions.

In order to use the IsInRole(), you have to populate the User Principal object.  The easiest place to do that is in the [Global.asax event BeginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx).  Also take a look at creating a [Custom Role Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27955/Developing-custom-ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-prov).